# Return the value of if statement in case when it's not null

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

How to return the value of my expression when it's true

```
SELECT if(((SELECT SUM(kcal) 
from jadlospis 
WHERE data ="2022-07-18" and uzytkownik_id=1 
GROUP BY DAY(data)) as expr) IS NULL,expr,'0')
```

```
#1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax obok 'as expr) IS NULL,expr,'0') LIMIT 0, 25' w linii 4.
```

How can i resolve my problem?

Comment: What problem - please publish error message if you have one. and move the alias to the end of the expression.

Comment: The problem is with the syntax.

#1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax obok 'as expr) IS NULL,expr,'0') LIMIT 0, 25' w linii 4.

It doesn't allow me to name the expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use an alias in the `IF()` function. Repeat the full expression instead.  Besides , redundant parenthesis can be removed. Try this:

```
SELECT if(
    (SELECT SUM(kcal) 
    from jadlospis 
    WHERE data ="2022-07-18" and uzytkownik_id=1 
    GROUP BY DAY(data)
    ) IS NULL,  -- don't use an alias
    (SELECT SUM(kcal) 
    from jadlospis 
    WHERE data ="2022-07-18" and uzytkownik_id=1 
    GROUP BY DAY(data)
    ), -- repeat the full expression 
    '0'
        ) 
;

-- in this case, it's better to use the IFNULL(expr1,expr2) function which returns expr1 if it is not null ,otherwise returns expr2 .
SELECT ifnull(
    (SELECT SUM(kcal) 
    from jadlospis 
    WHERE data ="2022-07-18" and uzytkownik_id=1 
    GROUP BY DAY(data)
    ) ,  
    '0'
        ) 
;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this syntax `IF(condition, true_value, false_value)`, if the condition is true 'true_value' will be returned. In your case, 'true_value' is NULL because the expression 'expr' upon being true returns NULL as per your condition.

Comment: But how to get the value